ubuntu 24.04 won't configure nvidia-driver-390 using software and update
Upgraded to U24.04 and decided to run the nouveau graphic package this time. But it has continues to have issues, the desktop icons keep moving and some only load occasionally
I tried to install the nvidia-390 drivers thru software updater but have been unsuccessful in getting a configured load.
Repeated message is
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-390 (--configure): installed nvidia-dkms-390 package post-installation script sub process returned error exit status 10

and the output ends errors were encountered while processing:
nvidia-dkms-390
nvidia-driver-390
I have a nvidia suppled NVIDIA-Linux-x86-390.157.run file but I am not sure running that is a good idea.
 *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF100GL [Quadro 4000]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: a3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-d1ffffff memory:c0000000-c7ffffff memory:c8000000-cbffffff ioport:7000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff

ubuntu-drivers devices
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:05:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000006DDsv000010DEsd00000780bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF100GL [Quadro 4000]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin


What's the next step??
Thanks for looking
Jim
